# How to return a default value in a object's attribute

Tags: javascript

It is a bit too hard to find a fitting title for the problem. So if you have an object:

```js
const primary = {
  green: {
    dark: '#dark' <-- hex code
    light: '#light'
    ...: '#...'
  }
}
```

I would like the following functionality.

1. If I do `console.log(primary.green)` this should return a default hex string: `#def` and not the object `{ dark: ..., light: ... }`
2. If I do `console.log(primary.green.dark)` this should return the hex string `#dark`

A clear option would be to add `default` attribute inside the `primary.green` object. So it would be `primary.green.default`. However I would like to avoid this.

I have tried to do thinks with getter, but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't per se.

JavaScript has no way of giving you a value for `x` but a different value for `x` if you then go on to access a property of it.

What you can do is add a `toString` method to the object so if it is used in a context that casts it to a string, you get the value you want instead of `"[object Object]"`.

```js
const primary = {
  green: {
    dark: '#dark',
    light: '#light',
    toString: function () { return this.dark; }
  }
}

console.log(primary.green.dark);
console.log(primary.green);
console.log(`${primary.green}`);
```

This is obviously quite a lot of work to do by hand so you'll probably want to build a function to transform the code you wrote into code where every object has a suitable `toString` method on it.

```js
const ThemeColor = {
    toString: function () { return this.dark; }
};

const myThemeData = {
  green: {
    dark: '#dark',
    light: '#light',
  },
  red: {
    dark: '#dark',
    light: '#light',
  },
};

const themeBuilder = (themeData) => Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(themeData).map(
        ([colorName, versions]) => [colorName, {...ThemeColor, ...versions}]
    )
);

const primary = themeBuilder(myThemeData);

console.log(`${primary.green}`);
console.log(`${primary.red} / ${primary.red.dark} / ${primary.red.light}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be to use a proxy getter to return a function that takes the non-default option as an argument. Not exactly the behaviour you want, but similar.

```
const primary = {
    green: {
        dark: '#dark',
        light: '#light'
    }
}

const handler = {
    get: (obj, prop, receiver) => {
        return (key) => obj[prop][key] || obj[prop].dark
    }
}

const proxyPrimary = new Proxy(primary, handler)
console.log(proxyPrimary.green())
console.log(proxyPrimary.green('light'))
```